# Any one aware of what format the OLD IBM PTS (personal typing system) used

Tags: legacy, data-conversion

I have been trying to write a program to convert my father's old PTS.  I assumed it was standard EBCDIC but when I convert to ASCII I get mostly junk.   Any one have any knowledge about PTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the [PS/2 version](http://www.obsoletecomputermuseum.org/ibm-pts), it's DOS 3.x & WordPerfect.  They were around at a certain large energy company when I worked there, but with the advent of 80286-class workstations & decent laser printers, they went away.

IIRC, EBCDIC never made it off the mainframes & AS400s.  I seem to recall some experimental PCs (fuzzy memory), but they died quickly.